TailwindCSS breakpoints smaller than `lg` override all styles in Flask application
I'm developing a Flask app, and have run into a very strange issue where the md breakpoint and smaller always apply regardless of screen size. I was able to recreate this issue with the following steps:

Create a new directory and install TailwindCSS (npm install tailwindcss, npx tailwindcss init)
Set content directories appropriately ("./templates/**/*.html")
Create a basic Flask app which includes compiled TailwindCSS
Attempt to apply styles with md breakpoint.

From this basic setup, here's some code:
tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./templates/**/*.html",
    "./static/src/**/*.js"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

base.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='dist/css/output.css')}}">    
  <title>Test App {% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test App</h1>
<section>
  <header>
    {% block header %}{% endblock header %}
  </header>
  <main>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
  </main>
</section>
</body>
</html>

home.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
  <h2>{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}</h2>
{% endblock header %}

{% block content %}
  <p class="text-green-500 md:text-red-500">
    Learn more about this project by visiting the About page.
  </p>
{% endblock content %}

In this incredibly minimal example, the text colour will not change with the md breakpoint as expected, but will if the lg or xl breakpoint is used. What could be causing this?

This issue was caused due to a lack of
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
in the head of the HTML.
